# How to remove the hyphens and the middle numbers in R

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```html
df<-read.table (text=" ID   Range

1   1-2-3
2   1-2-3
3   4-5-6
4   4-5-7
5   10-11-12
6   10-11-12
7   14-16-17
8   19-20-21
9   10-11-12
10  12-13-14

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table.

```html
  

  ID    Range
    1   1-3
    2   1-3
    3   4-6
    4   4-7
    5   10-12
    6   10-12
    7   14-17
    8   19-21
    9   10-12
    10  12-14
```

The logic is to remove the middle numbers and keep only one hyphen.

It seems this script does not work

```html
 gsub("-", "", df$Range)
```

Comment: Use `sub("-\\d+", "", df$Range)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `sub`

```
df$Range <- sub("-\\d+", "", df$Range)
```

-output

```
> df
   ID Range
1   1   1-3
2   2   1-3
3   3   4-6
4   4   4-7
5   5 10-12
6   6 10-12
7   7 14-17
8   8 19-21
9   9 10-12
10 10 12-14
```

Comment: Simple, but great! Thank you , upvoted

Answer (score 3):

We could use `str_replace` with regex `\\-` for the hyphen and `\\d+` for digits after the hyphen:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Range= str_replace(Range, '\\-\\d+', ''))


   ID Range
1   1   1-3
2   2   1-3
3   3   4-6
4   4   4-7
5   5 10-12
6   6 10-12
7   7 14-17
8   8 19-21
9   9 10-12
10 10 12-14
```